# Excel data to SQL Server using SpreadSheetGear dll

Tags: asp.net, .net, excel, spreadsheetgear

Can anyone please let me know if there is any API provided by third party SpreadSheetGear dll to save data from Excel to SQL Server ( similar we do using macros)

**My requirement :** I have to download data from web application using spreadsheetgear and then after I change the data and do some operation on the excel (button click/row change) then data should be saved back to SQL Server DB

Thanks
Ram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SpreadsheetGear has no APIs to interact directly with databases, unfortunately, so you would need to roll your own solution to get data to/from a worksheet and database.

FWIW, SpreadsheetGear does offer methods like IRange.[CopyFromDataTable](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.8.0/#SpreadsheetGear2017~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~CopyFromDataTable.html)(...) to copy DataTable data into the specified range of cells.  Or to generate a DataTable or DataSet from workbook data, you can use a variety of other methods:

- IRange.[GetDataTable](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.8.0/#SpreadsheetGear2017~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~GetDataTable.html)(...)
- IRange.[GetDataSet](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.8.0/#SpreadsheetGear2017~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~GetDataSet.html)(...)
- IWorkook.[GetDataSet](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.8.0/#SpreadsheetGear2017~SpreadsheetGear.IWorkbook~GetDataSet.html)(...)

Keep in mind these methods have no binding mechanism which would keep the contents of the worksheet data in sync with the DataTable/DataSet data or vice-versa; just a simple copy of the data is made.